# How to organise parallel computation on cluster using python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I need a way to map some functions(first level of hierarchy) on different cores inside one node, and some functions (second level of hierarchy) map on different nodes.If I where use something like C++,I would use threads for first level and processes for second level, but I use python and I have only processes. So, I need a way to run in parallel first level functions from second level function (as I know default python libs doesn't implement nested parallelisation)   Cluster has OpneMpi and openMP software.Maybe I can use some solutions with mpirun

Comment: The easiest approach would be using [ipython-parallel](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/parallel/) which uses internally many cool tools like zeromq and mpi.

Comment: but I restricted to run interactive software on cluster, only sh scripts with sbatch utility.